Confused about this usage of 見かけで以て
飼い犬の拒否をなだめる飼い主、という見かけで以て酷く殺伐とした内容だ。うすら寒すぎて笑いそうになる。
The context is a bit hard to explain, but fundamentally the main character is watching an assassin dog owner scolding his pet killer dog who refused to perform the deed. So I guess in the last part of the sentence he's pointing out the situation is almost too funny.
I'm stumbled on how to take 見かけで以て here. という見かけで I assume is akin "though catching sight of.."
But I don't quite get why で以て is used here and how the second part connects to it?

で以て【もって】 (or を以て) is a way of saying で as a method/means/cause marker. It's simplest to consider it an old-fashioned or literary way of saying "with" or "by".

メールでもって連絡する
= メールをもって連絡する
= メールで連絡する
to contact by email
外見でもって判断する
= 外見をもって判断する
= 外見で判断する
to judge by appearance

In this case, という見かけでもって seems to mean something along the lines of "judging from (the appearance of) ～", "with ～ (alone)" or "just by looking at ～".

飼い犬の拒否をなだめる飼い主、という見かけで以て酷く殺伐とした内容だ。
A pet owner soothing a resisting dog — that alone tells how terribly grim it is.

(The translation may need to be adjusted depending on the previous context. What does 内容 refer to? Is the speaker reading a story?)

No, he's standing a few meters from them. The owner tried to kill him but stopped in the middle of it to scold his dog, so the scene comes off as uncanny I suppose.

@Kawase_K Then the 内容 may refer to what someone said. Either way, it has little to do with the interpretation of でもって.
